# Incrementing column in formula by 5 when dragging

Tags: excel

Im trying to develop a SUMIF formula in Excel which where the "Sum_Range" column increments by five for each time i drag it. Currently, i'm trying to use the OFFSET formula, however, cannot find a way to make it increment as I want. The formula looks as follows:

```
=SUMIF('Customer profitability cal.'!$D:$D;'Output - Customer Profitability'!$A7;OFFSET('Customer profitability cal.'!$E:$E;0;5))
```

For now, the OFFSET will always just be five as I have locked column E - but even if I unlocked it, it would only increment by one for each drag.

Any ideas?

Best,
Nikolaj

Answer (score 3):

If you have a sequence `0, 1, 2, 3, ...` but needs `0, 5, 10, 15, ...`, then do  multiplying by 5: `0*5, 1*5, 2*5, 3*5, ...`

The function `COLUMN(A:A)` returns 1. If dragged this one column to right it gets `COLUMN(B:B)` and returns 2. If dragged further it gets `COLUMN(C:C)` and returns 3. And so on. `(COLUMN(A:A)-1)` leads to 0, 1, 2, 3, ... if dragged to right. So `(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*5` leads to 0, 5, 10, 15, ...

So for your case:

```
=SUMIF('Customer profitability cal.'!$D:$D,'Output - Customer Profitability'!$A7,OFFSET('Customer profitability cal.'!$E:$E,0,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*5))
```

Or as with your example, using semicolon as paraneter delimiter:

```
=SUMIF('Customer profitability cal.'!$D:$D;'Output - Customer Profitability'!$A7;OFFSET('Customer profitability cal.'!$E:$E;0;(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*5))
```